# Finding solution with Jacobi method

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

We all know the Jacobi method, used to find the solution to $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ when $A$ is $n\times n$ matrix, $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{b}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, can turn the equation to
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{x}^{(n+1)}=D^{-1}\mathbf{b}-D^{-1}(L+U)\mathbf{x}^{(n)},\quad n=1,2,\ldots
\end{equation}
where $D$ is the diagonal elements of $A$. $L,U$ is the lower triangle part and the upper triangle part respectively. I already known the matrix $A$ is diagonally dominant matrix, so Jacobi method converges and has an exact solution. Now I want to know how to get the expression of $\mathbf{x}^{(n)}$ when given the start vector $\mathbf{x}^{(0)}$. Suppose $D^{-1}\mathbf{b}$ and $-D^{-1}(L+U)$ are both given. I prefer to solve it without computing program.

Comment: Have you worked out the formula for the first few values of $n$. What pattern do you see?

Comment: Should I use $I+D^{-1}(L+U)$ replace the second since $I-A+A^2-\ldots=(I+A)^{-1}$?

Comment: @CarlChristian I did find it like the next one: $$\mathbf{x}^{(n)}=(-D^{-1}(L+U))^{n}\mathbf{x}^{(0)}+(I-D^{-1}(L+U)+(D^{-1}(L+U))^2+\ldots)D^{-1}b$$

Comment: Okay I know how to get it. The iteration matrix is $T$, then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbf{x}^{(n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}T^{n}\mathbf{x}^{(0)}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}T^{j}\mathbf{c}=(I-T)^{-1}\mathbf{c}$$ for iterative equation like $\mathbf{x}^{(n)}=T\mathbf{x}^{(n-1)}+\mathbf{c}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diagonally dominant matrix is convergent. The $n$th power of iteration matrix $T=-D^{-1}(L+U)$ is converged to zero.
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbf{x}^{(n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}T^{n}\mathbf{x}^{(0)}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}T^{j}c=(I-T)^{-1}c
\end{equation}
It is convergent to the solution of equation. Hence the question is closed.